# How to get caretIndex from a TextArea as TextField

Tags: actionscript-3, textarea

I saw a lot of examples of using .caretIndex to get the index of cursor inside a TextField text, but I'm using TextArea and there is no such property, only selection index. So how do I get the cursor index position from a TextArea?

Edit: ok, I did a test and selectionBeginIndex is returning a value. Is it "right" to use it, or is there some specific way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `selectionBeginIndex`

According to [Adobe's documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/TextArea.html):

`If there is no selection, this value is set to the position of the caret.`

Comment: Thanks, is good to have the guarantee of using the right property. This documentation is bad translated to my language, the value, if no selection, is set to "circumflex" and the default is zero, but the english version leave no doubt.